# Load testing using JMeter with multiple concurrent users account

Tags: jmeter, performance, load-testing

I am facing a problem with JMeter. Like if I am login with my account with Team (In my application one module is Team in which we have to fill some fields which are common for all users, I want to login with different user, create a team and fill the fields). Can we fetch team URL from CSV file if we stored this in a CSV file?

@ Is this possible with Selenium and/or JMeter without opening browser?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible with JMeter without opening browser. You can pass the URL as a parameter using the CSV file. For this you need to use '[CSV Data Set Config](https://docs.blazemeter.com/customer/portal/articles/1740850-using-csv-data-set-config)'.

[image]

After passing the URL from the CSV file, you can fill all the fields required for creating a team from the CSV too, this way you will have different data for different teams.